# Array of objects, change to new structure when conditions meet

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following array: I would like to group everything by the `timestamp` and sum the `real` if `subGroup` meet, per `mainGroup`. see below the result I'm after...

```
var arr = [
  {
    mainGroup: 'A',
    subGroup: 'B',
    real: 100,
    timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    mainGroup: 'A',
    subGroup: 'C',
    real: 150,
    timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    mainGroup: 'B',
    subGroup: 'D',
    real: 123,
    timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    mainGroup: 'B',
    subGroup: 'Y',
    real: 542,
    timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z'
  }
]
```

The result would be:

```
[
  {
    A: 250, // 250 is sub B real + sub C real.
    B: 665, // 665 is sub D real + sub Y real.
    timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z'
  },
]
```

My code so far:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    mainGroup: 'A',
    subGroup: 'B',
    real: 100,
    timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    mainGroup: 'A',
    subGroup: 'C',
    real: 150,
    timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    mainGroup: 'B',
    subGroup: 'D',
    real: 123,
    timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    mainGroup: 'B',
    subGroup: 'Y',
    real: 542,
    timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z'
  }
]

let b = arr.reduce((a, item) => {
  a[item.timestamp] = a[item.timestamp] || {};

  Object.assign(a[item.timestamp], {
    [item.mainGroup]: item.real
  });

  return a;
}, {});

Object.keys(b)
    .map(timestamp => Object.assign(b[timestamp], { timestamp }));

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object for referencing the group.

With [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var array = [{ mainGroup: 'A', subGroup: 'B', real: 100, timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z' }, { mainGroup: 'A', subGroup: 'C', real: 150, timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z' }, { mainGroup: 'B', subGroup: 'D', real: 123, timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z' }, { mainGroup: 'B', subGroup: 'Y', real: 542, timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z' }],
    grouped = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.timestamp]) {
        this[a.timestamp] = { timestamp: a.timestamp };
        grouped.push(this[a.timestamp]);
    }
    this[a.timestamp][a.mainGroup] = (this[a.timestamp][a.mainGroup] || 0) + a.real;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var array = [{ mainGroup: 'A', subGroup: 'B', real: 100, timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z' }, { mainGroup: 'A', subGroup: 'C', real: 150, timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z' }, { mainGroup: 'B', subGroup: 'D', real: 123, timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z' }, { mainGroup: 'B', subGroup: 'Y', real: 542, timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z' }],
    grouped = array.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!hash[a.timestamp]) {
                hash[a.timestamp] = { timestamp: a.timestamp };
                r.push(hash[a.timestamp]);
            }
            hash[a.timestamp][a.mainGroup] = (hash[a.timestamp][a.mainGroup] || 0) + a.real;
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var array = [{ mainGroup: 'A', subGroup: 'B', real: 100, timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z' }, { mainGroup: 'A', subGroup: 'C', real: 150, timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z' }, { mainGroup: 'B', subGroup: 'D', real: 123, timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z' }, { mainGroup: 'B', subGroup: 'Y', real: 542, timestamp: '2017-01-15T01:00:00.000Z' }],
    grouped = array.reduce((hash => (r, a) => {
        if (!hash[a.timestamp]) {
            hash[a.timestamp] = { timestamp: a.timestamp };
            r.push(hash[a.timestamp]);
        }
        hash[a.timestamp][a.mainGroup] = (hash[a.timestamp][a.mainGroup] || 0) + a.real;
        return r;
    })(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina could you tell me why you pick forEach over a reduce? you are defiantly algorithm master :D

Comment: the result value (the array) does not change for each iteration, it is always the same array, so no need for reduce, but if you really like to use reduce, i could add the code as well.

Comment: Yeah I would love to compare the two! Thanks again

Comment: I try to write it in ES6, how would the final line look line? `}, {}, []` wont work

Answer (score 1):

a) Initialize properly your accumulator initial value

b) Sum A,B values - you are reassigning values (overwriting)

```
arr.reduce(function(acc, next){
    if (next.timestamp) {
        acc.timestamp = next.timestamp;
    }

    if (acc[next.mainGroup] === undefined) {
       acc[next.mainGroup] = 0;
    }

    acc[next.mainGroup] += next.real;

    return acc;
}, {})
```

or, in a code reduced form:

```
arr.reduce(function(acc, next){
    acc.timestamp = next.timestamp || acc.timestamp;

    acc[next.mainGroup] = (acc[next.mainGroup] || 0) + next.real;

    return acc;
}, {})
```

Comment: Thanks, what if the keys are unknown? A, B